# Why does Java (on one particular installation) think I'm self-signing?

Tags: java, code-signing-certificate

On one particular machine (Windows Server 2012R2 with current updates and JRE) I'm getting the classic "Your security settings have blocked a self-signed application from running" error.  Obviously I can get around it by making my launch site (which is internal and for our own internal use only) trusted.  However, I would like to solve the root cause if possible.

What's making this difficult to solve is:

A) It's NOT self-signed.  It's signed with a JKS that contains our COMODO certificate and the chain of authority updates from COMODO (root and intermediate).  It did however start when we received our latest certificate, was never a problem with the old one.

B) All the other machines we have accept the certificate as properly signed by COMODO (Windows 7, 8.1, Mac, Linux).  It's just this one server that thinks it's self-signed.

Ideas?

Comment: Every valid certificate chain ultimately points back to a certificate that is its own authority.  I'd guess it's *that* cert your machine is objecting to, not the one at the front of the chain.  Make sure the affected server has the appropriate COMODO certificate(s) in its trusted root certificate store.  That might even be as simple as applying an available Microsoft update.

Comment: Well, that server is fully up to date and the problem still exists.  Also of note, I've now got a report from one of our Mac users that his particular machine doesn't like the certificate either.  No trouble tickets from any of our other Mac users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that for some reason, various Windows versions that we have installed can end up with dramatically different sets of root certificates.  All the machines that worked fine had around 320 some certs installed, the machines that fail to work only had around 70.  COMODO eventually issued us a replacement certificate designed to validate against a different root...  That works fine on all our machines.

Comment: I just bought a COMODO code signing cert from a reseller and am facing the same fundamental problem. I would be interested in the name of the replacement root cert you received. The only COMODO root cert I can find in the oracle java 1.8.0_u45 cacerts truststore is called "AAA Certificate Services".

Comment: @Zalumon I don't have access to that info right at this second, but I can tell you that if it's an emergency you can contact Comodo, explain the issue, and they will re-issue under the alternate root pretty quickly.  I'll make a note to check next time I'm in the office too and update...

Comment: @Zalumon - "COMODO SHA-256 Code Signing CA"

Comment: hm, I meant: what is the root of your new certificate. I would have expected either "UserTrust..." or "AddTrust...". Based on this: https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/Default/Knowledgebase/Article/View/620/1/which-is-root-which-is-intermediate

Comment: It uses the "AddTrust".

Comment: thanks, that makes sense. I also finally solved my issue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31220258/1124509